# How to convert string to var object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, webbrowser-control

I am developing a windows application with a webbrowser control. I want to parse a string and convert it to a var object in JavaScript. The string I have created in C# function and send it to the JavaScript on the HTML page. The string is below:

```
var str=  "{"title": 'Mr', "Name": 'Samy', "Age": '30', "Gender": 'Male'};
          {"title": 'Mrs', "Name": 'Sully', "Age": '25', "Gender": 'Female'};
          {"title": 'Mr', "Name": 'John', "Age": '35', "Gender": 'Male'};
          {"title": 'Mr', "Name": 'Amy', "Age": '32', "Gender": 'Female'}";
```

in HTML page JavaScript below:

```
          var newStr= JSON.parse(str);
```

The problem is it is not working. If I have one string then it works. But when a group of string then it is not a string. I think I need to split with the string with (;) separator. The output I need is below:

```
[object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]
```

Comment: Why are you not using a JSON array?

Comment: @Stefan, C# send the string through a parameter to HTML page. where I am getting the parameter by following code `var str= window.external.SendDatas();`

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```js
var str = `{"title": "Mr", "Name": "Samy", "Age": "30", "Gender": "Male"};
          {"title": "Mrs", "Name": "Sully", "Age": "25", "Gender": "Female"};
          {"title": "Mr", "Name": "John", "Age": "35", "Gender": "Male"};
          {"title": "Mr", "Name": "Amy", "Age": "32", "Gender": "Female"}`;

const data = str.split(';').map((obj) => JSON.parse(obj));
console.warn(data);
```

Comment: when I use `const data = str.split(';').map((obj) => JSON.parse(obj));` then an error shows-----`"An error has occured in the script on this page"`

Comment: Need to see more of your code to understand why you would get that error.

Comment: @losif, `var str= window.external.SendLocations();
        const data = str.split(';').map((obj) => JSON.parse(obj));`

Comment: what is str `window.external.SendLocations();` the same a the value you put in your question?

Comment: @losif, Yes. The str I have mentioned in my question. Actually, I'm getting the data from the SQL server datatable with an if statement. I am appending each data row from the database.

Comment: you could try to just parse every row and then push them directly to an array

Comment: @losif, Actually, `var str={"title": "Mr", "Name": "Samy", "Age": "30", "Gender": "Male"}; {"title": "Mrs", "Name": "Sully", "Age": "25", "Gender": "Female"}; {"title": "Mr", "Name": "John", "Age": "35", "Gender": "Male"}; {"title": "Mr", "Name": "Amy", "Age": "32", "Gender": "Female"};` is working in web application but I'm using windows application. So it is show script error. I don not know why. Can you solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just edit your input string...

```js
var str = `[{"title":"Mr","Name":"Samy","Age":"30","Gender":"Male"},
{"title":"Mrs","Name":"Sully","Age":"25","Gender":"Female"},
{"title":"Mr","Name":"John","Age":"35","Gender":"Male"},
{"title":"Mr","Name":"Amy","Age":"32","Gender":"Female"}]`;
          
console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Comment: I use 'var obj = '['+str+']';var strNew = JSON.parse(obj); '  but strill it shows  error `An error has occured in the script on this page`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, but you say you are creating the string literal in c#? In that case, the C# syntax is invalid (it should give compilation errors)

I corrected it:

```
 var str = @"[{ 'title': 'Mr',  'Name': 'Samy', 'Age': '30', 'Gender': 'Male'},
              { 'title': 'Mrs', 'Name': 'Sully', 'Age': '25', 'Gender': 'Female'},
              { 'title': 'Mr',  'Name': 'John',  'Age': '35', 'Gender': 'Male'},
              { 'title': 'Mr',  'Name': 'Amy',   'Age': '32', 'Gender': 'Female'}]";
```

- For multiline string-literals, in .NET, you need to make the string verbatim, by starting with `@`. Only then, a string literal is allowed to be more than one line.
- You cannot use `"` inside string literals because it means **the end of the string literal** to C#, so the compiler will give errors. I have replaced all your `"` with `'` because json allows this. If you really need `"`, you must **escape sequence** it by doubling all `"` -> `""`. (this applies to verbatim string that start with @, in normal C# string literals you must use `\"`)
- JSON separates items with `,` not `;`
- JSON lists of items must be encapsulated in `[` and `]`